# parse extended json output file from cucumber with php

Tags: php, json, parsing, cucumber, encode

i am tring to parse a special json content. I got this as an output file from a cucumber execution. The goal is it to decode some values like the **name** the **status** and some other content. How can i encode that.
Another concern would be a transformation of json into a CSV.
It is not important for me to use php. Java or Perl would be an alternative.
This file I am gonna call in php with:

```
$jsonconntent = file_get_contents("/home/xxx/test1.json");
```

The json conten looks like this (I posted only the beginning):

```
[
    {
    "uri": "features/complete_ski.feature",
    "id": "complete_ski_with_time",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "Complete_Ski_with_time",
    "description": "",
    "line": 1,
    "elements": [
    {
        "id": "complete_ski_with_time;time_part_preamble",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "name": "time_part_preamble",
        "description": "",
        "line": 3,
        "type": "scenario",
        "before": [
        {
            "output": [
              "Default Timestamp start: 1516024716000"
            ],
            "match": {
              "location": "features/support/env.rb:32"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 191690
            }
        },
        {
            "match": {
              "location": "capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:13"
        },
        "result": {
          "status": "passed",
          "duration": 52117
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "location": "capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:21"
        },
        "result": {
          "status": "passed",
          "duration": 25885
        }
      }
    ],
    "steps": [
      {
        "keyword": "Given ",
        "name": "a Android A-Party",
        "line": 4,
        "output": [
          "Got handset with number unvisable, IMSI: notfor, android-Id: yourfone, VNC: 11111, port: 9981"
        ],
        "match": {
          "location": "features/step_definitions/idrp_steps.rb:11"
        },
        "result": {
          "status": "passed",
          "duration": 1415024760
        },
        "after": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "features/support/env.rb:24"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 264339
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`$data = json_decode($jsonconntent, true);`

You will have the data with javascript objects as arrays, not PHP objects.

To save it as CSV, it depends on the structure of the data. In this case, it is complicated:

```
{
  "uri": "features/complete_ski.feature",
  "id": "complete_ski_with_time",
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "name": "Complete_Ski_with_time",
  "description": "",
  "line": 1,
  "elements": [
    {
      "id": "complete_ski_with_time;time_part_preamble",
      "keyword": "Scenario",
      "name": "time_part_preamble",
      "description": "",
      "line": 3,
      ...
```

How do you put the data in the column `elements`? Data is so nested that it cannot be transformed into a tabular format with column headers and one value per column in each row.

As to how to access the data, you can do this:

```
$first_element_id = $data[0]['elements'][0]['id'];

foreach ( $data as $item ) {
    $uri = $item['uri'];
    foreach ( $item['elements'] as $element ) {
        $name = $element['name'];
    }
}
```

As asked in one of the comments, this is how to access the 'Default Timestamp start':

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item['elements'] as $element) {
        foreach ($element['before'] as $before) {
            if (isset($before['output'])) {
                foreach ($before['output'] as $output) {
                    echo sprintf("%s\n", $output);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The elements were put in the columns by Gherkin/Cucumber/Ruby

Comment: And after I added this code line what will be changed or what I have to do next to get the information i want?

Comment: I checked your edit. First thanks for help. After paste the code suggestion from you I got this PHP Errors:                                                                PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

Comment: So the error was guily by me. Your code: $first_element_id = $data[0]['elements'][0]['id'];                                      works. Can you explain me that shortly please? Thank You!

Comment: It's basic array manipulation. I suggest you read [PHP's array manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to get a better understanding. Also, do `var_dump()`s of `$data`, `$data[0]`, `$data[0]['elements']` and so on, and you will see the structure of the data you are working with.

Comment: Bear in mind that JSON has a JavaScript-like syntax, so arrays (with 0-based indices) are represented with `[]` and in fact omit the index while objects (a.k.a. associative arrays, with anything as key) are represented with `{}` and their keys are shown. But in PHP you treat them the same way, e.g. `$arr[2]` vs `$arr['items']`.

Comment: Also, you can paste your JSON code in this [JSON parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/).

Comment: yes. I can use an online parser. But I need one on my Server to work with the output with other scripts and bounded on timesatmps. Can you do one last thing for me and say me how do I come In the next segment. The json file goes on so: https://pastebin.com/3FuFSbvs

Comment: Please say me how can I get this String  output":[

    "Default Timestamp start: 1516024716000

I dont come behind this. If you say me that I can work.

Comment: I add it to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank You very much for this. But what is the mystic behind this? Why are all Timestamps printed out now and not only the one which is in the first output parameter. How can I go one? Such like you? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. As I said, it's array manipulation. Read the link, really. You could access the first one directly by using something _like_ `$data[0]['elements'][0]...` but it is very error-prone, e.g. arrays can be empty. That is why it is always better to iterate 0-based arrays and check the existence of keys in associative arrays.

Comment: The directly way you named first is for my case the right one and works. Maybe you can say me a way how I can go one. Look I have this one $first_element_id = $data[0]['elements'][0]['id']; How can I first test for example with an "if-case" if this genereally exists in the array before I assign it to an variable?